# Changing MS Exchange Settings through API (rather than dashboard)

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am new to Microsoft Exchange Server(2016). I am trying to fetch or change Exchange server mail spam filter settings using API call through the code. However, I have not come across any documentation that helps me with this. What would be the best way to do this? If someone can share documentation with me, it will be great.

Comment: Does the Exchange Management Shell not provide what you need?! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/exchange-management-shell?view=exchange-ps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change server setting then you will need to use the Exchange Management Shell cmdlets which you can call from Managed code using something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ff326159(v%3Dexchg.140)

The specific cmdlets and examples for the AntiSpam settings can be found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/antispam-and-antimalware/antispam-protection/configure-antispam-settings?view=exchserver-2019